# Flexible method of detecting focused control change

Tags: delphi, focus, components, delphi-2009

I need to write a component which will register in self other components and will detect if one of the registered components receive focus.

For example for my component `TFocusObserver` I am registering three objects.

```
FocusObserver.Register(MyMemo);
FocusObserver.Register(MyButton);
FocusObserver.Register(MyEdit);
```

And now if one of this components receives focus then `FocusObserver` is firing up some notification event.

I was looking how to detect a focus change and have found that `TScreen.OnActiveControlChange` is exactly what I need. So my component could hook up to this event. The problem is that more than one `TFocusObserver` might exists or later in a future somoene else might want to use `OnActiveControlChange`.

This is the time in which I would benefit from multicast event - it would solve my problem right away.

I was thinking how to solve this and I have currently two ideas:

1. Extending somehow `TScreen` so it would provide one more event for me.
2. Introduce an intermediate object which will hook up to `OnActiveControlChange` and expose one multicast event for other objects.

After a brief look at the sources I have no clear idea how to solve it by using first idea and the second idea has the drawback that someone can simply assign another method to `OnActiveControlChange` and everything fill fall apart.

Will be grateful for some suggestions.

Comment: If you said *more than one TFocusObserver might exists* at one time I guess, did you mean that all of them should have get notified about those focus changes or only one of them ?

Comment: What is the base class of TFocusObserver?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your focusObserver class can be a descendant of TWinControl, than you can do this:

```
TFocusObserver = class( TWinControl )

  procedure CMFocusChanged(var Message: TCMFocusChanged); message CM_FOCUSCHANGED;
end;
```

and

```
procedure TFocusObserver.CMFocusChanged(var Message: TCMFocusChanged);
var
  LControl: TWinControl;

begin
      LControl := TWinControl(Message.Sender);

      if LControl <> nil then
      begin
        form1.Caption := lControl.Name;
      end;
end;
```

Here the main idea is to watch `CM_FOCUSCHANGED`.

**Second approach:**

When registering the Control you replace it's `WindowProc`. Here's a little code snippet:

```
TRegisteredComp = class
  private
    fControl: TControl;
    fowndproc: TWndMethod;
    procedure HookWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  public
    constructor Create( c: TControl );
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TFocusObserver = class
  private
    l: TList;
   public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure reg( c: TControl );

  end;
```

and under implementation:

```
constructor TFocusObserver.Create;
begin
  l := TList.Create;
end;

destructor TFocusObserver.Destroy;
var i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to l.Count - 1 do
    TRegisteredComp(l[i]).Free;
  l.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TFocusObserver.reg( c: TControl );
var
  rc: TRegisteredComp;
begin
  rc := TRegisteredComp.Create( c );
  l.Add( rc );
end;

constructor TRegisteredComp.Create(c: TControl);
begin
  fControl := c;
  fowndproc := c.WindowProc;
  c.WindowProc := HookWndProc;
end;

destructor TRegisteredComp.Destroy;
begin
  fControl.WindowProc := fowndproc;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TRegisteredComp.HookWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if ( Message.Msg = CM_FOCUSCHANGED ) and
    ( TControl(Message.LParam) = fControl ) then
    form1.ListBox1.Items.Add( 'focused: ' + fControl.Name );

  fowndproc( Message );
end;
```

than just register the control you want to watch, example:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  fo := TFocusObserver.Create;
  for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
    fo.reg( Controls[i] );
end;
```

How does it sound?

Comment: Thanks, this solution has two drawbacks: 1 - I must place this component on a form so it could capture change of focus. 2- It will detect the focus change only on the form on which it sits. However, if nothing better comes up I'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: I appreciate your time and the second approach works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could remember the value of Screen.OnActiveControlChange
just before your component replaces it.

```
FOnActiveControlChange := Screen.OnActiveControlChange;
Screen.OnActiveControlChange = MyOnActiveControlChange;
```

Then in xxx.MyOnActiveControlChange

```
begin
  // what you wanted to do here
  ...

  if Assigned( FOnActiveControlChange) then begin

    // Forward to previous subscriber.
    FOnActiveControlChange( Sender, ...);
end;
```

But this only works if you're in control of the application, if someone else uses your component and he/she has other components that also use OnActiveControlChange things might go wrong.

Comment: Thanks Marck, as I stated in my question - someone else might change assignment for TScreen.OnActiveControlChange. So this won't work...

Comment: Well, another option is to listen for CM_FOCUSCHANGED messages.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post but here it is :

If using a third party library is an option, you could always use Spring4d

I implemented something similar in the past. It goes in the lines of :

```
uses

Spring;

type

TActiveControl = class(TObject)
private
   FEvent : Event<TNotifyEvent>;
   class var FInstance : TActiveControl;
   function GetOnActiveControlChanged : IEvent<TNotifyEvent>;
   procedure DoOnActiveControlChanged(Sender : TObject);
public
   class property Instance : TActiveControl read FActiveControl;
   property OnActiveControlChanged : IEvent<TNotifyEvent> get GetOnActiveControlChanged;
   constructor Create;
   destructor Destroy; override;
end;

TSubscriber = class(TObject)
private
   procedure DoOnActiveControlChanged(Sender : TObject);
public
   constructor Create;
   destructor Destroy; override;
end;

...

function TActiveControl.GetOnActiveControlChanged : IEvent<TNotifyEvent>
begin
  Result := FEvent;
end;

constructor TActiveControl.Create
begin
  Screen.OnActiveControlChanged := DoOnActiveControlChanged;
end;

destructor TActiveControl.Destroy;
begin
   OnActiveControlChanged.Clear;
   FOnActiveControlChanged := nil;
   inherited;
end;

procedure TActiveControl.DoOnActiveControlChanged(Sender : TObject);
begin
  if OnActiveControlChanged.CanInvoke
     OnActiveControlChanged.Invoke(Sender);
end;

procedure TSubscriber .DoOnActiveControlChanged(Sender : TObject);
begin
   // OnActiveControl has been triggered
end;


constructor TSubscriber.Create;
begin
   TActiveControl.Instance.OnActiveControlChanged.Add(DoOnActiveControlChanged); 
end;


destructor TSubscriber .Destroy


initialization

   TActiveControl.FInstance := TActiveControl.Create;

finalization

   FreeAndNil(TActiveControl.FInstance);
```

In this case I use a simple version of the singleton pattern for TActiveControl. You could also create an interface for it (IActiveControl) and inject it when necessary using IOC. This is a further step though.

This way, all your calls to Screen.OnActiveControlChanged should instead use TActiveControl.Instance.OnActiveControlChanged. Spring4d is awesome. There's lots of stuff in it, including multicast, IOC container, collections, etc. etc.